# multiple distributions on a single system

Tags: ros, kinect, pcl, ros-electric, ros-diamondback

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROS Electric, however I read that ROS Diamondback has an enhanced support as far as 2D/3D visualization and Kinect are concerned (that I require).

Can I install Diamondback on the same system (I'm using an Ubuntu 11.10 based PC) or should I just install the additional packages that are in Diamondback?

(My concern being any duplicity resulting in errors on having 2 distributions.)

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12588/multiple-distributions-on-a-single-system/) by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2012-01-10

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kshitij](https://answers.ros.org/users/1481/kshitij/) on 2012-01-18**:
^That was probably the case. Thanks.

**Comment by [Murph](https://answers.ros.org/users/176/murph/) on 2012-01-11**:
Where did you read about Diamondback being better for your uses? I use some kinect stuff and have only found improvement with Electric over Diamondback. Be sure you weren't just reading something discussing the time before Electric was released.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are installing from debian packages, installing multiple distributions is supported; simply install the packages from the distribution you're interested in.

That said, you cannot mix debian packages from different distributions, due to binary incompatibility, and nodes from different distributions are often unable to communicate with one another, due to changes in message formats.

As a side note, I would be surprised if Diamondback has better 2D/3D visualization tools. What in particular were you looking at?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2012-01-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-01-11**:
As @ahendrix says, you can install as many distributions as you like. To avoid mixing packages, be careful to set `$ROS_HOME` and `$ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` appropriately. See also: http://answers.ros.org/question/2491/upgrading-from-diamondback-to-electric-problems